conditional logic for dataweave code in mule 4
I need help on dataweave code. My requirement is to add the status field in the response based on the below criteria.
var manditory_field="D6V_Cod,D6V,DYR_Cod,DYR"
If any of the manditory_field value is null in the request then status value will be "Certified-Retry". If all manditory_field value is available then status value will be "Certified".
note: manditory_field values is dynamic. later other field can be added.
input:
        {
        "vin": "1234",
        "D6H": null,
        "D6H_Cod": null,
        "D6K": null,
        "D6K_Cod": null,
        "D6V": null,
        "D6V_Cod": null,
        "DCP": null,
        "DCP_Cod": null,
        "DI2": null,
        "DI2_Cod": null,
        "DJY": null,
        "DJY_Cod": null,
        "DXD": "04",
        "DXD_Cod": "CD",
        "DYD": null,
        "DYD_Cod": null,
        "DYR": null,
        "DYR_Cod": null,
        "DRC": null,
        "DRC_Cod": null,
        "DO9": null,
        "DO9_Cod": null,
        }

expected result:
        {
        "vin": "1234",
        "D6H": null,
        "D6H_Cod": null,
        "D6K": null,
        "D6K_Cod": null,
        "D6V": null,
        "D6V_Cod": null,
        "DCP": null,
        "DCP_Cod": null,
        "DI2": null,
        "DI2_Cod": null,
        "DJY": null,
        "DJY_Cod": null,
        "DXD": "04",
        "DXD_Cod": "CD",
        "DYD": null,
        "DYD_Cod": null,
        "DYR": null,
        "DYR_Cod": null,
        "DRC": null,
        "DRC_Cod": null,
        "DO9": null,
        "DO9_Cod": null,
        "status": "Certified-Retry"
        }  


I modified @sudhish_s solution to check that every mandatory field is present in the payload (using every()) and their values are not null.
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var mandatory_fields = ["vin", "DXD"]
---
payload ++ 
    if (mandatory_fields every ((namesOf(payload) contains ($)) and !(payload[$] is Null) )) 
    {
        status: "Certified"
    } else {
        status: "Certified-Retry"
    }

Output:
{
  "vin": "1234",
  "D6H": null,
  "D6H_Cod": null,
  "D6K": null,
  "D6K_Cod": null,
  "D6V": null,
  "D6V_Cod1": null,
  "DCP": null,
  "DCP_Cod": null,
  "DI2": null,
  "DI2_Cod": null,
  "DJY": null,
  "DJY_Cod": null,
  "DXD": "04",
  "DXD_Cod": "CD",
  "DYD": null,
  "DYD_Cod": null,
  "DYR": null,
  "DYR_Cod": null,
  "DRC": null,
  "DRC_Cod": null,
  "DO9": null,
  "DO9_Cod": null,
  "status": "Certified"
}


some can be used to determine if any of the keys belongs to the list of fields
%dw 2.0

import * from dw::core::Objects
output application/json
var mandatory_fields = ["D6V_Cod1","D6V","DYR_Cod","DYR"]
---
payload ++ (
    if (payload someEntry ((mandatory_fields contains ($$ as String)) and isEmpty($)))
    {
       status: "Certified-Retry" 
    }  else {
        status: "Certified"
    }
)


my requirement is to check the the mandatory_fields value in the input request. If any of the manditory field value is null or not available then status will be Certified-Retry else Certified.

@sudhish_s using namesOf() you don't need to convert the keys to String.

@Devendra Sorry, I somehow missed that. You can use the someEntry from Objects for this as well. I have updated the answer..  You can also use Aled's answer above.
@aled Good point. It completely skipped my mind.

Here first I have tried to check if key in input payload matches the mandatory field along with null check for the matched key
Then further I checked if total mandatory key should match the satisfied fields from the input i.e. if both the count matches exactly then its Certified and if count does not match then Certified-Retry
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var manditory_field="D6V_Cod,D6V,DYR_Cod,DYR" splitBy ","
var conditionmatch=payload mapObject ((value, key, index) ->
    do{
        var a=(manditory_field filter(($ ~= (key)) and !isEmpty(value)))[0]
        ---
        "matched": a

   }
)
---
payload ++ if(sizeOf(valuesOf(conditionmatch) filter(!isEmpty($))) == sizeOf(manditory_field))
   {
        status: "Certified"
    } else {
        status: "Certified-Retry"
    }


You can try with someEntry from Objects module to check if any value of mandatory fields are Null or not and update the status in the payload accordingly.
%dw 2.0
import someEntry from dw::core::Objects
var manditory_field = "D6V_Cod,D6V,DYR_Cod,DYR"
output application/json  
---
payload ++ (if (payload filterObject (manditory_field contains $$) someEntry ((value, key) -> value is Null))
  {
    status: 'Certified-Retry'
  }
else
  {
    status: 'Certified-Retry'
  })

